# nested loop pattern add some strings

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, pseudocode

can  everyone help  me to find pseudocode of this code, because I want to output of the code :

```
1****
12***
123**
1234*
12345
```

I want to have the stars on the output without spread syntax or magic,

the below code I wrote  here only print without the stars:

```js
var num = 5;

for(var i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++){
       var str = "";
  for(var j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++){
          str += j
  };
  console.log(str)
};
```

Comment: Why nested loops? Simply loop on the "numbers" part, then loop again on the "Stars" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the `str`, and `.repeat` asterisks `5 - length` times:

```js
var num = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  var str = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    str += j
  };
  str += '*'.repeat(5 - str.length);
  console.log(str)
};
```

[String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) is ES6, so for ancient browsers either use a polyfill or use a different method, like `new Array(6).join('*');`

Comment: is .repeat include build-in function? ?

Comment: Yes, for all non-ancient browsers

Comment: how about if we don't  use repeat ?

Comment: For ease of development, best to write in the latest and greatest version of the language and transpile/polyfill later IMO, but another option is to join an empty array by asterisks

Comment: You can just use another loop to add the `*` the appropriate number of times.

Comment: which position we should put that code on that for loop, on the first loop ? or second? @RobinZigmond

Comment: @PiL Unless you're *really* worried about performance, there's no need for another `for` loop, which would be a moderate amount of syntax - the `.join` method I mentioned in the answer is much shorter.

Comment: should the syntax be str += new Array(6).join('*')(5 - str.length); @CertainPerformance

Comment: @PiL `.join` returns a string, not a function, so you can't call a string like that. Pass the length (plus one) into the `new Array`

Comment: i stilll dont understand, can u give example?

Comment: @PiL it would go after the second loop (*after", not inside).

Comment: @PiL `str += new Array(6 - str.length).join('*')` But `.repeat` is preferable

Comment: should we use condition also if we want to make those number replace another string, example on the bottom number 12345 , and I want to make that number change to me 12three45 @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more loop to add '*' after the loop to print numbers

```js
var num = 5;

for(var i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++){
  var str = "";
  for(var j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++){
    str += j
  };
  for(var k = j; k <= num; k++) {
   str += '*'
  }
  console.log(str)
};
```

Or you can use condition in for loop and let inside `for` iterate from 1 to `num`

```js
var num = 5;

for(var i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++){
  var str = "";
  for(var j = 1 ; j <= num ; j++){
    str += j <= i ? j : '*'
  };
  console.log(str)
};
```

Comment: should we use condtion also if we want to make thos number replace another string, example on the bottom number 12345 , and i want to make that number change to me 12three45,